# How to Mock A Simple API call (Get Todos ) in ComponentDidMount - React + Typescript + Jest + Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

## The app

The app is a simple To Do List. This App gets the todos from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?&_limit=5.

### What I am trying to do

Test an API call that is executed in ComponentDidMount in **App.tsx**.

I want to mock the API call and return a list with two items. Then check if there are two items in the array or state.

### What files are important for you?

1. App.tsx (Component to be tested)
2. ToDoList.test.tsx (Contains test function)

#### Small part of App.tsx to simplify it

```js
class App extends Component {

public state: IState = {
    items: [],
    value : 5,
    deleteItemParent : this.deleteItemParent
  };


  getAllTodos = async () => {
    await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?&_limit=${this.state.value}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ items: json })
      });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllTodos();
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps : any, prevState: any) {
  // Updates todo's if state changed
  if (prevState.value !== this.state.value) {
    this.getAllTodos();
  }
}

render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
            <AddToDo addToDoParent={this.addToDo}/>
            <div>
                Todo's : {this.state.value}
            </div>
            <ToDoList items={this.state.items} deleteFromParent={this.deleteItemParent}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### ToDoListMock.test.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow , mount, ShallowWrapper} from 'enzyme';
import App from "../App";
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(
      [
        {
          title: "Todo1",
          completed: false
        },
        {
          title: "Todo2",
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    )
  })
) as jest.Mock<any>

it("must contain 2 items in state after mock api call", async () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res));
  // await jest.requireActual('promise').resolve()

  // Collect items from state
  const itemsFromState : any = wrapper.state('items');

  // Expect it to have a length of 2
  expect(itemsFromState.length).toBe(2);
})
```

#### The Error

> Expected: 2
> Received: 0

#### EDIT

#### SetupTests.ts

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import ReactSixteenAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new ReactSixteenAdapter() });
```

I noticed an error while doing the test.
[image: Error fetch await]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you have to change to make it work:

- You forgot to trigger to fetch your notes as your component mounted by putting to `componentDidMount`:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.getAllTodos();
}
```

- Like you said, the data response is the list which is not a literal object, so you have to change your mock returning an array instead of literal object with `todos` property. But to make sure it runs well, we have to move `beforeEach`:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
 global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve([ // Returns as an array here
            {
                title: "Todo1",
                completed : false
            },
            {
                title: "Todo2",
                completed : false
            }
        ])
    })
  ) as jest.Mock<any> 
})
```

- Delay your test before getting the state since you have a mock promise need to be done:

```js
it("must contain 2 items in state after mock api call", async () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  
  // Delay with either following ways to wait your promise resolved
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res));
  // await jest.requireActual('promise').resolve()

  // Collect items from state
  const itemsFromState: Array<any> = wrapper.state('items');

  // Expect it to have a length of 2
  expect(itemsFromState.length).toBe(2);
})
```

- I also created a link for you to compare your code to: https://repl.it/@tmhao2005/Todo

Comment: Hey thank you very much! But it still did not work :(. I indeed forgot to add the componentDidMount function. The state of items should be json because the actual app worked if I did items: json. I receive the todos in the state and the items show on the screen. 

I also added the delay in the test file but the test fails. Expected: 2 Received: 0. I edited the code in my post :). I also tried the outcommented line of the await.
You got any more ideas?

Comment: If the data returns right thing, you mock data is likely wrong which is supposed to be an array instead of literal object. I edited the answer to point out the right mock

Comment: Hey sorry for my late reaction, I will try to respons faster. I edited the code like you said but still the same error. I noticed I receive another error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". I edited in a screenshot in my post.

Comment: I dropped the replicated link for you https://repl.it/@tmhao2005/Todo

Comment: I checked the code and it's exactly the same except for 1 thing. I use Typescript files. And in the testfile I put this "as jest.Mock<any>". Maybe that is not correct. Is there maybe another way to mock a function?

Comment: Nope it's just typing only which is not gonna affect anything in your code. Can you try to re-visit the link above since I've switched to Typescript you for? Try to compare your code with my code again then you would see where the issue is

Comment: I am literally mindblown. I checked it 3 times but the code is the same. I edited my post, so maybe you can spot a mistake but I don't see it :/. How is this possible :( ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224620/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-appel-taart).

Comment: I also disabled all my other tests but this did not make a change

Comment: Is the error still persistent? Or just the the expectation is not right for now? Things look right but not sure if you can increase the timeout around 20ms would help like: `await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 20))`. If it's still failed, just share me a reproducible repo

Comment: Yep it still fails even with the 20ms delay. Here is a link to the repo : https://github.com/Julianlu1/testing-with-jest. By the way, I really appreciate your help :). Is it also possible to not make it a global fetch and just put it in the test function itself? What will happen if I want to test multple api calls?

Comment: I find out that you have to move your mock of `fetch` to `beforeEach` to make it work. Not sure what you have done with your repo though :)

Comment: Hey I have answered in the chat! :)

Comment: Ah I've just seen it. I'm not sure why it didn't work with your repo which might be an interesting case :) (it's likely related to either CRA or your setup)

Comment: Ahh thanks for your help anyway bro!, I just followed a tutorial on the web. I followed this one: https://medium.com/@feralamillo/create-react-app-typescript-testing-with-jest-and-enzyme-869fdba1bd3. The tutorial said something about ejected and not ejected version. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I chose the not ejected version by the way.

Comment: If you think you're able to manage to control client things working together, you should eject. Or you shouldn't do that :)

Comment: Hmm okay, I think im going to try to make a new project then haha

Comment: hey tmhao! How are you?, I do not know how to contact you but can I ask you something quick about jest testing and typescript ?

Comment: Hi friend. I'm doing well. You have a new question, don't you?

Comment: Hello! ahahah I like it that you know I have a question ;p. I do have one. I am trying to test a component. I meant with React-Testing-Library  and Jest btw. Would be nice if you have time to answer it :P. Here is the stackoverflow link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811875/react-testing-library-typeerror-trim-is-not-a-function-when-using-render

Comment: I had seen it before you answered :) anyway let have a look at my answer then

Comment: Ah yes I see it :D

Comment: Also, is it best practise to mock the png jpeg and svg in a test?

Comment: Looks like I've had a few answers around this one but it's hard to find them again though :). You can use this package to mock them though since they should be excluded while testing https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-stub https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#mocking-css-modules

Comment: Aah yes I already use that! Could you explain why it is best practice to mock images and svg?

Comment: Normally, we don't do anything with assets during the test so it doesn't make sense to keep them included (possibly make tests run slower)

Comment: But what if I want to test if there is an image on the screen ;p ?

Comment: In case of that, we should just try mock return a name of image or path as identity like this one has done the same job https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-svg-transformer.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks! btw did you get my chat messages :D?

Comment: So in that case, I need to remove the mocks and add jest-svg-transformer in my jest config right?

Comment: Yep it returns a identify for you to check your image during the test :)