# React Testing Library - TypeError trim is not a function when using render

Tags: javascript, react-testing-library

I am creating a simple test with Jest + React Testing Library. However, when I try to render my  it crashes in de code. This is strange because the application does run smoothly. It seems like the props are undefined or empty.

Test file:

```js
test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { container } = render(<App />);
});
```

App:

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Child} from './Child';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
          <Child/>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child of App:

```js
import * as React from "react";

export class Child extends React.Component<TheProps>{
     const testString = this.props.testVariable.trim();

     render(){
            return(
                <div>Just a simple div</div>
            )
        }
}

interface TheProps{
     testString : string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here you have missed to pass the property of `testVariable` to `<Child />` so if you mark the prop is optional, then you should check it before proceed anything. Additionally, you code looks wrong by defining a variable inside a class like above.

Anyway you can either define your default property or null check the property:

```js
export class Child extends React.Component<TheProps> {
    // set default props
    static defaultProps = {
        testVariable: ""
    }

    render() {
        const testString = this.props.testVariable.trim();
        return (
            <div>Just a simple div</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Or null checking:

```js
const testString = this.props.testVariable?.trim();
```

Comment: I also recommend to use functional component which is much easier than using a class then you can take advantage of using hooks as well.

Comment: But how should I do it if I do not want a null check? Should I then pass the parameter in my test? I will keep the functional component in my mind :).

Comment: Because now we are sure the testVariable is empty when running the test. But that is not best practise right?

Comment: You have to determine which props should be required or not. If required, you must provide it. Otherwise, you just simply provide the default value or null checking

Comment: Hmm okay, how would I be able to send those props to the Child in my test? Because I am rendering <App/>. Would it be something like this? :<App testVariable="hello   world"/>

Comment: Nope. The right one is `<Child testVariable="your value" />`

Comment: Yes but I am rendering <App/> in my test. This <App/> makes use of Child. How would I do that in this situation ;p?

Comment: Hmmm it still crashes when I do the following : ```const testString = this.props.testVariable?.trim();```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227606/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-appel-taart).

Comment: If you wish to pass from the `App`, then you have to define props for the app then pass down to `Child` then. `<App testVariable="the value" />` then `<Child testVariable={props.testVariable} />`

Comment: Ah okay I get it.

Comment: Isn't the check not a bypass? ```const testString = this.props.testVariable?.trim();
``` because now the testVariable is not a string but undefined (I think).